# Supabase RLS insert policy: only authenticated user, owner of the record

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have a table called ebooks with rows a foreign key row called user. and i want to create a policy which checks only the users can only insert if the user column is same as the id of the user who is inserting. i hope u understand. here is what i tried,

```
CREATE POLICY "Enable insert for authenticated users only" ON "public"."Ebooks"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR INSERT
TO authenticated

WITH CHECK (auth.uid() = user)
```

it throws this error

```
Error adding policy: failed to create pg.policies: operator does not exist: uuid = name
```

any help would be great, thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of `user` column ?
If it's `varchar`  type;

Then You need to cast `auth.uid()` also to `varchar` type

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast uid to varchar type before you compare with user.

So, There is only change in your last line of code.
`WITH CHECK (auth.uid() = user)`

```
CREATE POLICY "Enable insert for authenticated users only" ON "public"."Ebooks"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR INSERT
TO authenticated

WITH CHECK (auth.uid()::varchar = user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I think that adding doublequotes to the column name solved this and `column does not exist` errors for me.

So `WITH CHECK (auth.uid() = "user")`.